# Edge does not show/use TLS/SSL until refresh

Tags: ssl, nginx, microsoft-edge, letsencrypt

We have a webapp that uses 'Let's encrypt' certificates (and the nginx webserver).
The certificates are automatically renewed (a cron job runs every day and we get a new cert every 2 or 3 months).

With the first certificate everything worked. But now, that we got a renewed certificate, the Edge browser seems to have a problem.

When we visit the site, it seems that Edge does not recognize/use TLS encryption:
[image]

you can see that the URL is `https` (so I guess the connection is actually encrypted), but the info window (when you click the `(i)` icon) shows a message, that the connection is not encrypted.

When we press F5 to relaod the page, everything seems okay again:
[image]

So I guess, that Edge may somehow still have the info about the old (expired) cert and thus shows the wrong info message.

note:
we do have HSTS enabled in the NGINX config - but that should not matter: [SO-Ref](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/144843/should-i-activate-hsts-with-let-s-encrypt-certificates)

How can we avoid this? i.e. we want Edge to automatically use the new cert and not force our users to press F5.

Comment: How do other browsers behave?

Comment: @garethTheRed I am not sure how other browsers behave, because it is tricky to reproduce. After you click F5 once, the issue is gone. However, I think that I did not see the issue in Firefox. In Chrome I also saw a strange issue: it showed the okay-lock icon in the address bar, but the cert detail page showed the expired cert. Also after F5 the issue was gone.

Comment: It's going to take a very long time to figure it out if you can only test once every three months.  You could look at SChannel's ClientCacheTime - 10 hours by default.  It might also be worth creating a lab CA (OpenSSL maybe) with certs that last much shorter in order to speed up the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the issue is related to the web-page being a PWA and that we had initially used a www-only cert.

**Details**:

- when setting up the server we first created a www-only-certificate for e.g. `www.myapp.com`
- but we forgot to include the naked-domain in the cert, so some hours later we created a new cert for `myapp.com` and `www.myapp.com`
- the browsers that had already loaded the app had the issue described in the question

**Result**:
actually we just ignored the issue, because only few clients were affected and even for those, chrome does not show an error and the connection is still encrypted